# limit of continuous function in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

When I have a function, say $v$, continuous at $z_0$, then $\lim_{z\to z_0}v(z)=v(z_0)$. Does that imply that $\lim_{z\to z_0}iv(z)=iv(z_0)$, where $i$ is the imaginary number.

Also, if I have u as a function continuous at $z_0$ as well, is the function $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ continuous at $z_0$, I think yes, but the square root is throwing me off. Can anyone give me an idea for this one as well?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question is "yes". Generally, if $g : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} v$ exists, then $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} g(v(z)) = g(\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} v(z))$. In this case, take $g(z) = cz$ with $c = i$.

For second question, I think the answer is "yes", as long as $u^2(z_0)+v^2(z_0)\neq 0$. The problem is that there is a branch point of the function $h:z\mapsto z^{1/2}$ at $0$ and you are talking about $h( u^2 + v^2)$ here.

Note that when you speak of $\sqrt{\cdot}$, you have to specify the branch (there are two values of the square root for all nonzero $z$).

The square root function can't be defined as a continuous function on the whole plane. The reason is that if you start at a point $z_0\neq 0$ and travel along a simple loop that encircles $0$ and return to $z_0$, you will find that the value of $h(z)$ changes continuously as you travel along the loop but that you arrive back at $z_0$ with the value $-h(z_0)$, the "other" value of the square root. That means there will necessarily be points arbitrarily close to $z_0$ whose images under $h$ are not close, since $h(z_0)$ and $-h(z_0)$ are not close.

This problem is usually remedied by removing from the domain of $h$ an open ray emanating from the origin. The direction of the ray doesn't matter; the important thing is that it is an obstacle preventing a closed loop from encircling the origin. It doesn't even have to be a straight halfline, just a simple curve that starts at $0$ and escapes to infinity (it could even be a spiral!).